# Dask dataframe condition to compare column doesn't working

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I'm trying to compare the column names of a dask dataframe to then change the column data type, however my condition never is true:

```
column_name = "names"
print(f"Col Name: {column_name} \n") # names
# Change column datatype:
for i in dataframe_for_db.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist():
    if (dataframe_for_db[i] == column_name).any().compute() :
        # Change column datatype
        print("Column found. changing datatype : ")
        dataframe_for_db[i] = dataframe_for_db[i].astype(str)

print(dataframe_for_db.dtypes)
```

as you can see guys, I'm getting all the column names, but this doensn't work. The column name is setted above.

this condition never is executed:

```
if (dataframe_for_db[i] == column_name).any().compute() :
```

I want to change the column datatypes because then I need to store this dataframe in my database. I will only create the table name in the db and then run my script which will creates the columns of my table.

Any idea guys to fix this problem, I will appreciate it, thanks so much.

Comment: Won't `i` itself be the column name that you are looking for? `dataframe_for_db[i]` is all the data in the column.

Comment: I found that dataframe_for_db[i] throws: Dask Series Structure: How I can get the column name. thanks

Comment: for column in dataframe_for_db.columns: 
            if dataframe_for_db[column].name == column_name: This seem to be working however the column datatype is not changed dataframe_for_db[column] = dataframe_for_db[column].astype(str)

Comment: Thats all thats needed. Modified your example as answer due to comment limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import dask
 
 dataframe_for_db = dask.datasets.timeseries()¬
 print(dataframe_for_db.dtypes)
 column_name = "x"
 print(f"Col Name: {column_name} \n") # names
 # Change column datatype:
 for i in dataframe_for_db.columns:
     print(f"Processing column {i}")
     if (i == column_name):
         # Change column datatype
         print("Column found. changing datatype : ")
         dataframe_for_db[i] = dataframe_for_db[i].astype(str)

print("After Processing")
print(dataframe_for_db.dtypes)
```

yields

```
name     object
id        int64
x       float64
y       float64
dtype: object
Col Name: x

Processing column name
Processing column id
Processing column x
Column found. changing datatype :
Processing column y

After Processing
name     object
id        int64
x        object
y       float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Exactly. Hopes it helps other developers